# Если значение переменной равно то

Tags: php

Всем привет!
Как сделать

если например  index.php?dr=vova
значение переменной равно vova
то должна появиться картинка вовы
а
если например  index.php?dr=kola
значение переменной равно kola
то должна появиться картинка Коли
а
если например  index.php?dr=нет значения то картинка безликого

вроде правильно описал) спасибо за ответ

Comment: Громадное человеческое спаибо ua6xh !!! Очень сильно помог!

Comment: @Александр Дахно, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dr = $_GET['dr'];    
if(empty($dr)){ echo "dr is empty...";}
elseif($dr == 'kola'){ echo "kola";}
elseif($dr == 'vova'){ echo "vova";}
```

Можно так же сделать через оператор `switch`:

```
switch($dr){
   case 'kola':
       echo 'kola';
       break;
    case 'vova':
       echo 'vova';
       break;
    default:
       echo 'default';
}
```

Comment: а как теперь вставить что он выводит в код?
<img src="img/<?php $_GET['dr'];?>.jpg">  
так?

Comment: @Александр Дахно - ну так и вставляйте, вместо оператора `echo`

Comment: <img src="img/<?php echo ['dr'];?>.jpg">
так?
извини я только начал изучать это все

Comment: >извини я только начал изучать это все

тогда возьмите и прочитайте какую-нибудь книгу по php, иначе вопросов у вас будет гораздо больше, чем вам смогут ответить

Comment: <?php
$dr = $_GET['dr'];    
if(empty($dr)){ echo "dr is empty...";}
elseif($dr == 'kola'){ echo "kola";}
elseif($dr == 'vova'){ echo "vova2";}
?>

<h2><?php echo "$dr";?></h2>

выводит сразу два значения vova2 
и vova

Comment: @Александр Дахно, зачем так баловаться elseif? Это дурная привычка!

Comment: @Александр Дахно, потому что у вас после всех циклов ВСЕ РАВНО выводится echo"$dr"! - т.е. второй раз

Answer (score 5):

```
switch($_GET['dr']) {
  case 'kola':
print "<img src='kola.png'>";
    break;
  case 'vova':
print "<img src='vova.png'>";
    break;
  default:
print "<img src='nekto.png'>";
}
```

Comment: правильно, а то привыкают - elseif... elseif ))))